# Spring JPA and order by an input field

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a table like the below. I want to query using Spring JPA with a specific order. For instance, the query will be;

```
select * from test where id in ("1","3","2") order by case
    id
        when '1' then 1
        when '3' then 2
        when '2' then 3
    end

Table: test
| id | value |
|----|-------|
| 1  | A     |
| 2  | B     |
| 3  | C     |
```

I have to use SQL server, so there is no FIELD available like;

```
select * from test where id in ("1", "3", "2") order by field("1", "3", "2")
```

So, my question is whether Spring JPA has a good way to query data as the order I wanted?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.4.2/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query. Specifically the part about the `native query`.

Comment: @AmirM thank you for your answer. But, for my case, the value within the native query needs to be updated. That is, the value 1, 2, 3 at the example are actually a kind of UUID that changes every time. So, the native query doesn't help me.

Comment: @sung-p That native query can also take parameters, so you may set those values (1,2,3 or any other list of IDs) as parameters in the native query.